# output is affected by the next clock period

Tags: verilog, xilinx, synthesis, system-verilog, module

I am trying to write verilog code or or thinking about a circuit to do the function below. 
In the clock period n, if there is a falling edge on S1 then OUT is high for the next clock cycle (n+1), if no falling edge  is detected then OUT is low for the next clock cycle (n+1).

Is this possible? Can anyone show me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty similar to your earlier question about using two negative clock edges so you should have some ideas of what you can do.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I don't know how to process with next clock period. It has been a long time since I was doing verilog school day. I don't know if there is even possible with verilog. For the previous problem, everything is done in a clock cycle which seems easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have two different always blocks controlling one signal.

Here's my version to avoid that

```
always @(negedge s1 or posedge clk) begin
    if(clk)
        saw_a_falling_edge <= 1'b0;
    else
        saw_a_falling_edge <= 1'b1;
    end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    out <= saw_a_falling_edge;
end
```

This is inferring a DFF with asynchronous clear to drive `saw_a_falling_edge`. The `clk` signal is connected to the CLEAR input and the `s1` signal is connected to the clock. The D input is tied high.

If you did it the other way around then if the clock edge happened while `s1` was still low, the output wouldn't go high (violating the requested behavior per your timing diagram).

Be aware the above solution won't handle the case that `s1` goes low while `clk` remains high. It's not clear to me from your problem statement whether you need to handle that or not.

Comment: In the first always block, at rising edge of clk saw_a_falling_edge  is always 0. 
So will the second always block, out is always 0?

Comment: @anhnha, `saw_a_falling_edge` physically can't change until a few (maybe 100) picoseconds after the clock edge. The `out` flip-flop will already have decided what it is going to change to before that. It will actually change based on what the input was a few (10-100?) picoseconds before the clock edge. This is called "negative hold time".

Comment: To do FPGA design, you need to get used to flip-flops responding to the "old" values on their inputs, not waiting for the changes on the inputs due to other flip-flops changing on the same edge.

Comment: I missed that concept which made it difficult. I tried to test in Modelsim and it works well. However, when I tried with DFF in PSIM circuit simulator, sometimes it works, sometimes not. The problem is maybe ideal DFF. Also, in my case falling edge of S1 is very close to rising edge of clk.

Comment: @anhnha, Falling edge of S1 very close to rising edge of CLK will make this problem fundamentally difficult, regardless of what technology you use. Maybe re-evaluate whether this is the right way to solve your bigger problem.

Comment: This approach won't actually work, because as you say, the synthesis tool will treat `clk` as an asynchronous reset to a DFF -- which makes it level-sensitive, not edge-sensitive. This means that if the falling edge of `s1` occurs while `clk` is high, the event will be missed altogether.

Comment: @DaveTweed, fair enough. I wasn't sure from OP's problem description if it's required to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use the solution given in [verilog code with two falling edges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/432001/11683), followed by another DFF. Adjust the edge directions as needed.

Putting it all together, you get:

```
module saw_falling_edge (
  input s1,
  input clock,
  output reg out
);
  reg set_ff;
  reg reset_ff;
  wire q = set_ff ^ reset_ff;

  always @(negedge s1) if (!q) set_ff <= !set_ff;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (q) reset_ff <= !reset_ff;
    out <= q;
  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
input clk;
input s1;
output reg out;

reg saw_a_falling_edge;

always @(negedge s1)
    saw_a_falling_edge <= 1;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    out <= saw_a_falling_edge;
    saw_a_falling_edge <= 0;
end
```

In practice, this will probably fail timing analysis unless you can constrain `s1` appropriately against `clk`.

Comment: can you explain what "constrain s1 appropriately against clk" mean?

Comment: Essentially, you have to promise to the synthesis tools that `s1` won't change too close to a clock edge. Exactly how you do this will depend on what toolchain you're working with, and is a bit outside the scope of this question.

Comment: This problem is only in synthesis tool? Ideally in my project, falling edge will approach the rising edge of clk.

Comment: I think it's ambiguous what this will synthesize. Is `saw_a_falling_edge` produced by a DFF with asynchronous set (clocked by `clk`) or with asynchronous reset (clocked by `s1`). Better to use a single always block to define `saw_falling_edge` as one or the other (and to specify in a synthesizable way what happens if the clk edge happens when s1 is still low or s1 edge happens when clk is still high)

Comment: I don't think the exact behavior decribed by the Verilog is synthesizable in an FPGA.

Comment: I got this error while trying to compile the code: Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "saw_a_falling_edge"

Comment: @ThePhoton Can you come up with a better representation of the logic described by the OP? I don't see any obvious better way of representing this, but perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: This approach will work in most simulators, but most synthesis tools will reject the attempt to set a variable from two different `always` blocks.